# Mongo shell: is it possible to add a custom function to cursor?

Tags: mongodb

In the command line tool mongosh, is it possible to add a custom function and I can use it this way:
`>db.somecollection.myCustomFunc()`

Comment: Did you try? Perhaps you can add the function but it might be overwritten (i.e. removed) again by MongoDB at any time.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't care overwritten. I just want to know how to add.

Comment: Have a look at [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) but when you work with `mongosh`, have also a careful look at [Script Limitations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/limitations/) and [Database operations not always working in Classes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOSH-1305)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit db.somecollection is not a general object.

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(db.somecollection)` gives a big output. I think you could add some properties.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit db.somecollection is obviously a cursor object. My question is how to add custom property to it.

Comment: Why do you think `db.somecollection` is a cursor object? A cursor is returned by `find()` method. Anyway, you may find some information at https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.11/

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not asking what function to add. I'm asking how to add a function in shell.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I have no idea what you are looking for.

But purely based on your question, the solution is this one:

```
Object.defineProperty(db.getSiblingDB('so').getCollection("somecollection"), 'giveMeFive', {
   enumerable: true,
   writable: false,
   configurable: false,
   value: () => {return 5}
});
```

and the just use it

```
use so
db.somecollection.giveMeFive()
5
```

Or another example:

```
Object.defineProperty(db.getSiblingDB('so').getCollection("somecollection"), 'insertTwo', {
   enumerable: true,
   writable: false,
   configurable: true,
   value: (x) => { 
      db.getSiblingDB('so').getCollection("somecollection").insertMany([x, x]); 
      return 'OK'; 
   }
});

use so
db.somecollection.insertTwo({ val: 3 })
OK

db.somecollection.find()
[
  { _id: ObjectId("63ceb12b2545bff4a24f2872"), val: 3 },
  { _id: ObjectId("63ceb12b2545bff4a24f2873"), val: 3 }
]
```

But as written in my comment, when you restart the shell then your property gets deleted.